# Why can't I add elements after a GridView?

Tags: android, gridview, layout, button

I've got the following layout XML file:

```
<LinearLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
android:id="@+id/main_layout" android:layout_width="fill_parent"
android:layout_height="fill_parent" android:orientation="vertical">
<GridView android:id="@+id/main_grid_screen"
    android:layout_width="fill_parent" android:layout_height="fill_parent"
    android:numColumns="auto_fit" android:verticalSpacing="30dp"
    android:horizontalSpacing="10dp" android:columnWidth="90dp"
    android:stretchMode="columnWidth" android:gravity="center" />
<Button android:id="@+id/clickable_area" android:layout_width="fill_parent"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content" 
android:text="@string/view_items_area" />
</LinearLayout>
```

The GridView shows up perfectly fine; however, the Button below it is completely absent. If I place the Button tag above the GridView, it appears. What gives?

Comment: does the gridview also appear when you put the button above?  It might be because of the fill_parent layout_width/heights you're supplying, but that's just a guess.

Comment: Yes; I made an edit to the original post (I forgot that SO hates brackets)

Comment: Golly I feel dumb. Changing the height of the GridView from fill_parent to wrap_content fixed the issue.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I think it is because of the fill_parent attributes.  The GridView is most likely taking up the entire screen and blocking your view of the button.  You could try wrap_content instead.

Comment: Why this answer is approved. It is not working. It is not true